# Drop (copy) Previous mySql Tables Dir into upgrade MariaDB Directory

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I've finally moved over to MariaDB from mySql 5.6 on my Ubuntu 16.04 (upgrade from 15.10). I have about a dozen previous web data tables sets (Drupal v7.4x) which are current and still in use on my localhost (LAMP). I have sql backups, but I'm not sure if I can (or should) simply drop the old DB tables from the previous mySQL5.6 directory/folder into the newly created MariaDB dir. I'm not afraid to try or merely drop them into the dir, I just don't want to then spend more time fixing problems which I cannot foresee at the present.
If 'importing' rather than 'dropping in' the data-table SQL is the best approach then so be it, but my question is:

**What is the best approach to upgrading SQL to MariaDB?**

Thanks in advance for any advice on this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that would be the easiest. Just dump the databases using `mysqldump` and use `mysql` command line to import the databases. If there are any problems (like an invalid definer) you will get a notice and can fix it by editing the dump.